# Why does PyLance show reportArgumentType?

Tags: python, pyright

I have the following Python code which works fine (version 3.11).  Why does PyLance complain about this?

```py
import jinja2
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.BaseLoader)
template = templateEnv.from_string(my_string)
```

PyLance v2024.2.2 in VS Code shows this error:

```
Argument of type "type[BaseLoader]" cannot be assigned to parameter "loader" of type "BaseLoader | None" in function "__init__"
  Type "type[BaseLoader]" cannot be assigned to type "BaseLoader | None"
    "type[type]" is incompatible with "type[BaseLoader]"
    "type[type]" is incompatible with "type[None]"
https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportArgumentType
```

Answer (score 1):

PyLance expects an **instance** of `BaseLoader` classs or its subclass for `loader` argument, but in your code you pass the **class** itself and not **instance of the class**.

If you don't need any specific loading behavior that requires subclassing `BaseLoader`, you can simply instantiate it directly as follows:

```py
import jinja2

templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.BaseLoader())
template = templateEnv.from_string(my_string)
```